# How to use "as ... as" in a sentence?

Tags: as

I have a sentence using "as ... as". Could you tell me which sentence below is right?

A. Marine transportation is a high-risk industry as aviation.
B. Marine transportation is an industry as high-risk as aviation.
C. Marine transportation is as a high-risk industry as aviation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say none of the three are correct. I'd go for:

D. Marine transportation is **as high-risk an industry as** aviation.

Comment: Thank you Gustavson. I am wondering why B is not correct. There is a simple example on dictionary, say: She is a teacher as good as her mother. The structure of B is the same to the example, but B is not correct?

Comment: What is the dictionary where you say you found that example? I find it to be wrong.